# What does the "provisioning profile" means in iOS keychain?

Tags: ios, keychain

In the document of apple, it tells me that:

```
Note: On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile used to sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same provisioning profile across different versions of your application.
```

What does the "provisioning profile" means ? Is it the "Code sign" that I build the application ? Is it means that if I use the same "Code sign" to build two application, in each application I can access the same keychain.

ps:
  I want save some share string in keychain in iOS for different application. Just some share space in iOS for different application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's that thing you download after logging into developer.apple.com that you need in order to run an app on your device.

Comment: It is a file ending in `.mobileprovision` that you download